# Locate an Uncaught SyntaxError in Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, syntax-error

When I load my website with a couple of JavaScript files included, Google Chrome puts a `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier` in its developer tools console. Unfortunately, that's all:

[image: Screenshot of the console]

No line number, not even a file name. The red text is not clickable either. I have even browsed through the file tree in "sources", to no avail.

I am afraid this will be my silliest question ever. **How can I find out where the error is?**

The only other browser in my company, IE8, does not seem to have the error, at least I can't find any errors in the console of the IE8 developer tools. I cannot install Firefox to use Firebug either.

SO found 25 similar questions, but all of them list a piece of code and need help spotting the error in it. I don't know which code to list. If I did, I am sure I would have found the error already.

Comment: What JavaScript files? could you provide their content too?

Comment: Does your application call an AJAX function that returns JSON? I suspect the syntax error is happening during JSON.parse()

Comment: @Barmar - that's entirely possible, I will check.

Comment: @Rahil - no, because there are lots and the whole point is that I don't know which is affected. My question is not even to help me spotting erraneous JavaScript. It is about usage of the Chrome developer tools.

Answer (score 4):

Try going to the "sources" tab in the Google Chrome Devtools and enabling the "Pause on exceptions" option. Experiment with toggling "Pause On Caught Exceptions" if needed. That should potentially help you find out when the exception is occurring.

[image: Click the pause icon to break on exceptions]

Comment: Thank you very much. I have this option already on, but it never pauses anywhere. Note that this is not an exception but a syntax error, maybe that's the reason?

Comment: A syntax error should be caught as well (at least it does when I test it by evaling invalid code in the console).

Comment: It doesn't. When I turn on "pause on caught exceptions" it pauses in dozen places but none of them is the error. (Makes sense since it is "uncaught".) When I turn it off it does not pause in any place.

Answer (score 2):

The SyntaxError is coming from google trying to load a script tag, so there will not be an exception.

Chrome 87 will show a js file and line number.

Firebug will show line number and column(s).